# Is it possible to download an html file from a given webpage using my local network/browser as if I downloaded it myself with javascript or nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I’m a bit new to javascriipt/nodejs and its packages. Is it possible to download a file using my local browser or network? Whenever I look up scraping html files or downloading them, it is always done through a separate package and their server doing a request to a given url. How do I make my own computer download a html file as if I did right click save as on a google chrome webpage without running into any server/security issues and errors with javascript?

Comment: Downloading a single file is just a HTTP GET operation. Unless you want to do any interpreting js or viewing the html in a window, you don't need a browser for that - any tool that does http requests will suffice.

Comment: @Bergi Right I've seen these before, but I'm not sure they'd work for what im trying to do. My question is if its possible to do so as if my actual local computer did the request. In example, lets say I only have access to a website while I'm logged in to a wifi network. While i'm logged in, i can just go to a url, right click a page and save it, but if a http get tried to do so it would get some access/security error.

Comment: Well if the node.js program (or whatever HTTP tool) is running on your local computer and sends the same authentication headers as your browser does, the request is indistinguishable to the website's server and you will be able to access the content.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching a document over HTTP(S) in Node is definitely possible, although not as simple as some other languages. Here's the basic structure:

```
const https = require(`https`); // use http if it's an http url;

https.get(URLString, res => {
    const buffers = [];
    res.on(`data`, data => buffers.push(data));
    res.on(`end`, ()=>{
        const data = Buffer.concat(buffers);
        /*
        from here you can do what you want with the data. You can write it to a file
        with fs, you can console.log it using data.toString(), etc.
        */
    });
})
```

Edit: I think I missed the main question you had, give me a sec to add that.

Edit 2: If you're comfortable with doing the above, the way you access a website the same way as your browser is to open up the developer tools (F12 on Chrome) go to the network tab, find the request that the browser has made, and then using `http`(`s`)`.get(url, options, callback)`, set the exact same headers in the `options` that you see in your browser. Most of the time you won't need all of them, all you'll need is the authentication/session cookie.

Comment: Simpler to use a library like the `request` library that fetches the file/page for you in a simpler way.  But, the OP's question is more complicated than just issuing an HTTP GET.